# Odd DNN behaviour - Nesting html tags

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dotnetnuke

I'm experiencing an odd outcome where (I believe) I cannot access form fields due to one of my modules is generating a miniature  page inside the body tags, and seems to be resulting from either google ads or the form modules which seems to get loaded above the forms.

Does it sound like its coming from those modules? And if so is it likely these nested pages is what is causing my fields to be inaccessible? (behaviour is almost as if a DIV has been layed across the top of the forms, the lower fields are still acessible).

This is the section in the page source that concerned me:

```
..Normal HTML/Site code above...
.....
<!--DOCUMENTS SUCH AS BELOW KEEP GETTING NESTED-->
#document
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    </head>
    <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <iframe width="undefined" height="undefined" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="display:none" id="zrt_ads_frame1" name="zrt_ads_frame1" src="...">

        </iframe>
        <script>google_loader_used="sa";google_ad_format="undefinedxundefined";google_ad_unit_key="1117272154";google_show_ads_impl=true;google_unique_id=1;google_async_iframe_id="aswift_0";google_start_time=1393820506698;google_ad_handling_mode="EI";google_bpp=8;google_async_rrc=0;</script>
        <script src="..."></script><script>google_protectAndRun("ads_core.google_render_ad", google_handleError, google_render_ad, google_eid);</script>
        <iframe id="google_ads_frame1" name="google_ads_frame1" width="undefined" height="undefined" frameborder="0" src="..." marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no">
            #document
            <html>
                <head></head>
                <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></body>
        </iframe>
        <iframe id="google_osd_static_frame_3804139317944" name="google_osd_static_frame" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;">

        </iframe>
    </body>
```

Would this be my issue then?

Comment: Or is this just the default behaviour of an iframe?

Comment: Yes. iFrames have their own html documents inside them.

Comment: Righty-o thanks then, I'll continue on to find the real issue =)

Comment: Iframes do weird things inside DNN.  I had a link that opened an IFrame to another site, but when you closed the other side, it changed the CSS for the menu bar so it was 20% smaller.